# Worklight: App is not able to receive the push notification when in foreground

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a worklight app and when it is in foreground it doesn't receive any push notification. It works fine when in background.

The android log I can see is

```
12-14 00:35:35.304: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(26076): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
12-14 00:35:35.304: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(26076): GCM IntentService class: com.FinacleMobileApp.GCMIntentService
12-14 00:35:35.304: V/GCMBaseIntentService(26076): Acquiring wakelock
12-14 00:35:35.308: V/GCMBaseIntentService(26076): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-8
12-14 00:35:35.314: D/GCMIntentService(26076): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:107 :: WLGCMIntentService: Received a message from the GCM server
12-14 00:35:35.315: V/GCMBaseIntentService(26076): Releasing wakelock
12-14 00:35:35.323: W/GCMIntentService(26076): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:114 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.
12-14 00:35:35.326: D/GCMIntentService(26076): GCMIntentService.addToIntentQueue in GCMIntentService.java:147 :: WLGCMIntentService: App is on foreground but init is not comeplete. Queue the intent for later re-sending when app is back on foreground.
12-14 00:35:35.328: D/push(26076): Push$1.onReceive in Push.java:91 :: Push: Queuing message for dispatch to javascript
12-14 00:36:04.067: D/CordovaActivity(26076): Paused the application!
```

Can any one tell me, why this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would first correct the exception you're getting there regarding the badge to make sure this is not preventing it from correctly working:

> 12-14 00:35:35.323: W/GCMIntentService(26076): GCMIntentService.onMessage in GCMIntentService.java:114 :: Unable to update badge while received push notification, becasue failed to parse badge number null, badge must be an integer number.